# Aspose total for sharepoint

Tags: aspose

HI all,

> Is Aspose converts images to pdf.
>   Does Aspose Conversion from word to pdf requires MSOffice.
>   Does Aspose have separate pdf viewing functionality without using other softwares.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is Aspose converts images to pdf

Aspose.Pdf is not currently available for SharePoint, but we will roll out Aspose.Pdf for SharePoint soon. For .NET and Java platforms, yes images can be converted to PDF.

> Does Aspose Conversion from word to pdf requires MSOffice

MS Office is not required. Please see [this page](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/sharepoint-components/aspose.words-for-sharepoint/multiple-formats-support.html) for available conversion formats.

> Does Aspose have separate pdf viewing functionality without using other softwares

Aspose.Pdf provides only SDK to manipulate PDF documents using .NET, Java and other supported platforms. It does not depend on any other software from Microsoft, Adobe etc.